# How to authenticate user programmatically with spring data jpa repository?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I create demo project with spring data auditing.

I have `spring-security.xml` file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <authentication-manager>            
        <authentication-provider ref="userDao" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

It refers to spring data jpa repository `userDao`:

```
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

I expect spring data jpa to use this method to authenticate user.

Problem 2 is that I need to authenticate user programmatically. 
I tried to use `UserDetailsManager` but it has only `loadByUsername` method when I need to load user by username and password.

How to authenticate user programmatically with `UserDao.findByUsernameAndPassword` method?

P.S. `User` entity implements `UserDetails` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using a basic configuration taken from [Spring Security getting started page](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#scratch)

To authenticate programmatically a user you will need to put that user into the security context. In your specific case it may look like this:

```
User user = userDao.findByUsernameAndPassword("username", "password");
SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getName(), user.getPassword(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
authentication.setDetails(user);
ctx.setAuthentication(authentication);
```